# Bootstrap wysiwyg not able to add hyperlinks in IE

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, wysiwyg, contenteditable, rich-text-editor

The problem is if you click the insert hyperlink button in IE you will receive the drop down menu to enter the url, but you can not set focus on the textbox to enter a URL. everytime you click on the box the focus goes inside the below content editable

How to repro:

Open this link http://mindmup.github.io/bootstrap-wysiwyg/ in IE 8, click on the icon to add link and click on the URL box and try entering something

Comment: Code or a demo, please.

Comment: Open this link http://mindmup.github.io/bootstrap-wysiwyg/ in IE 8, click on the icon to add link and click on the URL box and try entering something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internet Explorer 8 is not supported by this editor. As the [documentation states](http://mindmup.github.io/bootstrap-wysiwyg/):

> Requires a modern browser (tested in Chrome 26, Firefox 19, ...reported by users to work in IE10).

A cursory glance at the source shows a couple of items that would prevent IE 8 support, such as the use of `FileReader` (Introduced in IE 10) and `window.getSelection` (Introduced in IE 9).

[CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/demo) supports Internet Explorer 8.

Comment: Yeah I agree but now i have already implemented it and I need to make it work with IE 8 too.... looks like a simple thing tht am missing

Comment: @ideate If the maintainers of the tool haven't extended support to Internet Explorer 8, that is likely because the work involved is too great in light of their reliance on modern APIs. IE 8 is half a decade old; getting it to behave like modern browsers can be very difficult at times.